# How to get the proximity

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I'm having some iBeacons around here.

Now how do I know that they are far or near?

Is there a way to get that from a beacon?

I've seen this https://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/ but I don't get it how to get from a beacon that it is far or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the open source [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/), this is a very simple process:

```
    @Override 
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
        for (IBeacon iBeacon: iBeacons) {
            if (iBeacon.getProximity() == IBeacon.PROXIMITY_NEAR) {
                Log.d(TAG, "The beacon is near");
            }
            else if (iBeacon.getProximity() == IBeacon.PROXIMITY_FAR) {
                Log.d(TAG, "The beacon is far");
            }            
        }
    }
```

You can see a larger example of this in the [Ranging Sample Code here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html).

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't make the link. Except I have a list of Beacons in android and not IBeacon. The problem is on my beacon I can't do .getProximity

Comment: Note that my answer above is for the Android iBeacon Library, which is a different framework with different APIs than the Estimote SDK in your question.  The link to the library is above.

Comment: EDIT: I'm using the preview SDK kit not the open source iBeacon Library.